# Rich snippets for "hproduct" not being displayed in Google, and returning error

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool, microformats

Some time ago I added rich snippets to product pages on an ecommerce website, but they have not shown in Google and the testing tool returns the following error:

> Warning: In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either `price` or `review` or `availability` needs to be present.

I know rich snippets are not guaranteed to show in Google, but the warning in the tool makes me think I have a problem, since if I put some other sites into the tool, they don't show the warning.

Here's [a sample page](http://www.computeroutpost.com.au/item/rb-gbm3/) and the results:

```
Extracted structured data

hproduct
description: Jeremy Walton’s new BMW 3 Series Enthusiast’s Companion is the only book you’ll ever need about BMW’s most popular line. BMW 3 Series Enthusiast's Companion discusses the roots of the... 
fn: BMW 3 Series Enthusiast's Companion 
photo: http://www.computeroutpost.com.au/store/thumb.ashx?code=RB-GBM3 
identifier:  
type: ISBN 
value: 0837602203 
price: 37.40 
currency: AUD 

Warning: In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either price or review or availability needs to be present.
```

Comment: John, It seems you resolved the issues. I can see the thumbnail image getting displayed in the given sample link. I am also facing same sort of problem where my og:image is not getting reflected in intermediate share window. Can you please check this link and tell me what is wrong? That will be a great help for me. google plus debugger identifies the ashx link well. [http://www.mckinsey.com/insights/americas/us_game_changers](http://www.mckinsey.com/insights/americas/us_game_changers) Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Hi @Peter. My problem was  to do with hproduct structured data rather than Facebook OG tags. I'm not sure if my problems are resolved but Google told me I must add availability data, although the rich snippets test tool says "or" availability not "and". For your problem I find that Facebook only checks the image once and if you change the meta tag it still uses the first image it found. Have you tried a different page that hasn't been shared on FB since you made the change? You are probably best starting a new question.